# upload files to amazon s3 with php issue (Uncaught exception 'Guzzl)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I m using amazon s3 server to upload files using php .
i tried this code

try {

```
    //Accessing config variable
    $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
            'Key' => "uploads/{$name}", //Where we actually store this on amazon S3. CAN USE $TMP_NAME
            'Body' => fopen($tmp_file_path, 'rb'), //Resource, open files - rb is reading.
            'ACL' => 'public-read' //Access control level, permissions as such
        ]);

    //Remove the file
    unlink($tmp_file_path);

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    die("There was an error uploading that file.");
}

        but getting error as Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Service\Exception\ValidationException' with message 'Validation errors: [Key] is a required string' in D:\php\htdocs\project\admin\server\aws2\ee\TestUploadAmazon\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand.php:357 Stack trace: #0
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($config)` to see the values. The messages suggests that `$config['s3']['key']` is empty. The key should be the full path to the file (i.e. directories + file name) within the bucket.

Comment: Also, `fopen` returns a resource. You cannot / don't want to set that as the 'Body'. You probably meant the content of the file instead of a file pointer resource so use `file_get_contents` for example.

Comment: @marekful after var_dump i m getting array as `array(1) { ["s3"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(20) "AKIAIJHMGNDXRH5JZ2XQ" ["secret"]=> string(40) "2YL9kqtuc1tw6tACXsRzyH/xfLuHEhkb2PBTQCMf" ["bucket"]=> string(16) "test777bucketname" } }`

Comment: This is just a suggestion. please check your bucket permissions - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Comment: @RenjithVR should i set permission to everyone or just 'Me'

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/08/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-php.html

Comment: See how did they fix the problem - https://www.codecourse.com/forum/topics/amazon-s3-upload-issue/2174

Comment: @RenjithVR yes i already checked those links .but geeting error

Comment: @webpic the same error?

Comment: From  that the website - **I fixed it. It was to do with the user permissions. For anyone else having the issue - go to your AWS user permissions and add the S3 administrator permissions.**

Comment: and please show the current errors.